# Reply to recruiter's email's tricky last line

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, email

A reruiter contacted me and the last line of his email was:

`Let me know if you have any interest in taking this conversation to the next step - hope to hear from you soon.`

While emailing him back, what should I ask him?

- should I ask him to schedule a phone call? Or is it too pushy?
- Should I ask him what the next steps are? (I think it might be too weak a response, and while trying to sound least sexist here, I'm a guy and in my experience, weak responses are not taken in positive light professionally)

Comment: It's hard to understand the context without the rest of the email (please don't share that here), but if the conversation was about a job then it's not unreasonable to ask what the next steps entail.  I think you're possibly overthinking the "weak response" bit :)

Comment: Sales 101 is end with an open question to get a response.    "Yes what is the next step"

Comment: @JaneS Still I can give brief background, the recruiter contacted me for a job opportunity. And yes, overthinking is my curse in general :-)

Comment: The guy is a cold-calling email recruiter. They are not picky. His thoughts on getting a reply from you are never going to be "Hmm, a weak response. I might not follow up with him" they are going to be "Whoopee! Someone replied to me! Where's my keyboard?".

Comment: @DJClayworth hahaha. That's epic. I'm used to ignoring such emails. This was from a bigger company, though he seems to be just cold calling, I still want to apply for this job. Hence asked the question.

Comment: In the reply you could give a preferred time window for a phone call. Make the time window narrow enough to give the impression of someone who also has other appointments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the comments, I think you are overthinking this :)

If you were discussing a role then the recruiter is confirming that you are ready to move on to the "next step" which is probably applying for the job.  You could respond by asking something like:

> Hi, Thanks for communicating with me.  I am definitely interested in the position, and would like to apply.  So how do we proceed from here?  If you like, we could have a chat on the phone to discuss the steps forward.
>
> Kind regards, CalZone

Or of course if you aren't interested, tell him no thanks otherwise :)

Comment: Thank you! I sent him something similar. I just wish my real name was as cool as Calzone. 

Comment: I know, I wish my real name was as cool as Jane!  Oh wait, it _is_ Jane... :)

Answer (score 3):

This is easy. The recruiter is trying to invite you to an interview or an engagement, which I assume the next step.

It will be your prerogative whether you want the interview to be over the phone, formally personal, or sometimes Skype if you live offshore.

Hope this helps.